# How do I set MaxConnPerRoute, ConnectionRequestTimeout, keepAliveStrategy in Spring WebFlux WebClient

Tags: httpclient, spring-webflux, spring-rest, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

we have the following custom connection pooling implemented for RestTemplate.

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnManager = 
                new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        poolingConnManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(restClientprops.getRestClientMaxPerRoutePool());
        poolingConnManager.setMaxTotal(restClientprops.getRestClientMaxTotalPool()); 
        HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder =  HttpClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(poolingConnManager)
                .setKeepAliveStrategy(DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy.INSTANCE)
                .setMaxConnPerRoute(restClientprops.getRestClientMaxPerRoutePool())
                .setMaxConnTotal(restClientprops.getRestClientMaxTotalPool()); 
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(restClientprops.getConnectTimeout()); 
        requestFactory.setReadTimeout(restClientprops.getReadTimeout()); 
        requestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(restClientprops.getConnectionRequestTimeout()); 
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClientBuilder.build());
        this.restTemplate =  new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

I am changing it to WebClient implementation, and this is what I could come up with.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
                    .create(ConnectionProvider.create("webclient-pool", restClientprops.getRestClientMaxTotalPool()))
                    .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, restClientprops.getConnectTimeout())
                    .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(restClientprops.getConnectionRequestTimeout()))
                    .doOnConnected(conn -> conn.addHandler(new ReadTimeoutHandler(restClientprops.getReadTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)))
                    .keepAlive(true);
```

1. Per this URL https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1159
   from what I understood connection request timeout is renamed to responseTimeOut in webclient httpclient. Is that accurate?
2. How should I set MaxConnPerRoute in webclient that is in the RestTemplate implementation?
3. Is keepAlive(true) accurate translation of setKeepAliveStrategy(DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy.INSTANCE)

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Per this URL https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1159 from what I understood connection request timeout is renamed to responseTimeOut in webclient httpclient. Is that accurate?

Yes that's true. More about all timeouts that can be configured for the `HttpClient` you can find in the [Reference Documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_timeout_configuration).

> How should I set MaxConnPerRoute in webclient that is in the RestTemplate implementation?

You can provide connection pool configuration per remote address (if that's what you mean with `MaxConnPerRoute`), see javadoc for [forRemoteHost](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/resources/ConnectionProvider.Builder.html#forRemoteHost-java.net.SocketAddress-java.util.function.Consumer-).

```
ConnectionProvider.builder("test")
                  .maxConnections(2) // default max connections
                  .forRemoteHost(<socket-address>,spec -> spec.maxConnections(1)) // max connections only for this socket address
                  .build();
```

> Is keepAlive(true) accurate translation of setKeepAliveStrategy(DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy.INSTANCE)

If you mean specifying whether the connection is persistent or not then **YES** this configuration has to be used. By default the connection **IS** persistent. If you mean `SO_KEEPALIVE` then **NO** and you have to use `.option()` configuration. You can find more in the [Reference Documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#connection-timeout).

```
HttpClient.create()
          .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
```

This configuration can be removed is you use the timeout settings provided by Reactor Netty:

```
.doOnConnected(conn -> conn.addHandler(new ReadTimeoutHandler(restClientprops.getReadTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)))
```